# How to get the value of parameter annotated with @RequestBody in a method interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller which has a `@RequestBody` annotation in one of its parameters. The parameter also has a custom annotation `@JsonData`.

```
public String updateUIMetadata(@PathVariable("caseId") final String caseId,
        @RequestBody @JsonData(schemaLocation = "schema/metadata_schema.json") final String metadataJson) {

          //...

}
```

I have a method interceptor which intercepts this method. I want to get hold of the value of `metadataJson` in my interceptor. I have tried using the `handler` object to get the `method` and the get the`parameters` but they do not seem to hold the value of the parameters. Is there anyway I can get the value with which `metadataJson` has been populated with in my interceptor class? Below is what I have tried.

```
public class ValidateJson implements HandlerInterceptor{

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {

        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        MethodParameter[] mparams = handlerMethod.getMethodParameters();
            Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
            Object[] allArgs = method.getParameters();
            Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
            for (int i = 0; i < parameterAnnotations.length; i++) {
                Annotation[] annotations = parameterAnnotations[i];
                for(Annotation annotation: annotations) {
                    if (annotation instanceof com.fico.cardinal.cm.utils.JsonData) {
                        System.out.println(allArgs[i].toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;    
    }
    return false;
} 
}
```

This just prints `java.lang.String arg1`

Comment: You're getting just the name of the parameter attending to the method's signature by reflection. Is far more simple if you do this with AspectJ instead.

Comment: Yes, it is. But due to some constraints, I can not use AspectJ. I was looking for a solution using Method Interceptor

Comment: Then your best chance is reading the payload using HttpServletRequest#getReader()

Comment: I too have a similar problem. I want to get the value of the parameter passed as part of the annotation in the interceptor handler function(prehandle), Can you explain in detail, how to handle this?

Comment: Searching for the answer in simular situation, wondered there is no any answer...